# How to identify columns which contain only tuples in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I identify the name of columns which contain only tuples in Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'I':[1,2,3,4], 'C':[80,160,240,80], "D":[[1,2], [1,2],[1,2], [1,2]],
               'F':[(1,2,3,4),(5,7,2),(9,6,2,5,7),(4,0,8,3,2)]})
df

    I   C       D       F 

0   1   80      [1, 2]  (1, 2, 3, 4)
 
1   2   160     [1, 2]  (5, 7, 2)

2   3   240     [1, 2]  (9, 6, 2, 5, 7)
 
3   4   80      [1, 2]  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)

df.dtypes

I    int64 

C    int64 

D    object 

F    object 

dtype: object
```

I thought of looking for `object` data type. But, objects other than tuples could result in `object` datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through column F and check if all the values are tuples.

If all the values are tuples, then the result of this will be True else False.

```
print (all(isinstance(x,tuple) for x in df['F']))
```

The output of this will be

```
True
```

If you want to check for all the columns in the dataframe, you can give something like this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    print ('column :',i, 'is a tuple : ', all(isinstance(x,tuple) for x in df[i]))
```

The output of this will be:

```
column : I is a tuple :  False
column : C is a tuple :  False
column : D is a tuple :  False
column : F is a tuple :  True
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to check this with `isinstance`

```
isinstance(df.F[0],tuple)

# True
```

If you want to check all value in a column then you'll need to loop through:

```
for i in df.F:
    print(isinstance(i,tuple))

#True
#True
#True
#True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```py
for i in df.keys():
    if(isinstance(df[i][0], tuple)): # true when tuple encountered
        print(i)
```